# Installing guided LDA package with pip on Windows

Tags: python, pip, lda

I am trying to pip install guidedlda on Windows. I installed Microsoft Visual Studio as installation requires it. When I the command I get Microsoft Visual `Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\Hostx86x64\\c1.exe failed with exit status 2 error`
Any ideas about how to solve it?

For full error please see: github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA/issues/43
(I also tried to implement suggested solution: copy pasting guidedlda.py, utils.py, datasets.py and the few NYT data set items into the original LDA package, did not really work)

Comment: Show complete error, please. Also look at https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA/issues/43

Comment: The error is exactly the same actually, I checked that issue on gitHun

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. Apparently there are issues on setting up guidedlda on windows OS.
Please check out this repo https://github.com/dex314/GuidedLDA_WorkAround
And follow instructions on the readme.
I was able to successfully set up guidedlda through that. :-)